# 数 as used in math - pronounced かず or すう?

Tags: pronunciation

Eg in definition of 根：ある数を何乗かした数に対するもとの数。

Is it pronounced かず or すう?

Comment: I have a feeling that mathematicians are fond of すう.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In everyday conversations, it's always read as かず. But in mathematical contexts, 数 on its own is usually read as **すう**. すう becomes dominant in math classes after you graduate from elementary school and start saying things like these.

> - 負【ふ】の**数【すう】**
>     negative number
> - 複素数【ふくそすう】とは実数【じっすう】 *a*, *b* と虚数【きょすう】単位【たんい】 i を用いて、 *a* + *bi* の形で表すことのできる **数【すう】** である。
>     A complex number is a number that can be expressed in the form *a* + *bi*, where *a* and *b* are real numbers and *i* is the imaginary unit.

Reading these 数 as かず is not wrong at all, but it sounds less technical.

Answer (score 1):

[数]{すう} is 音読み and [数]{かず} is 訓読み.
In general, 音読み of a single kanji itself does not mean anything while 訓読み is an understandable word.
Academic terms are often read with 音読み.

If a professor reads the difinition to students at his lecture, he probably read with 音読み.
If he is on a TV show and reads the definition to explain the concept of root, he should read 数 with 訓読み.